# array to bipartite graph in a fastest way

Tags: c++, math, graph

I have an array in file input.txt. Elements of it can be `'*'` and `'.'`
I need to make a bipartite graph from it. 
I created `int array m` to store elements. 
Now I'm reading number of lines and number of elements in line, then I read lines 1 by 1 and fill `int array m`, I put `1` in array if I have `'*'` in line and `-3` if I have `'.'` in line.
Then I go through the `array m` again and numerate all vertices(black and white). 
Then I go through the array again and watch all the elements, placed like `mas[i][j] (i+j)%2==1`. I took one of this element and look whether it has neighbours (elements `mas[i-1][j], mas[i][j-1], mas[i][j+1],mas[i+1][j]`). If this element does I push in `vector < vector <int> > g` like `g[mas[i][j]].push_back(neighbour)`. If element doesn't have neighbours, I delete it (I dont't need such elements in my problem).
How can I improve speed of this algorithm.

Here are some code:

```
    ifstream fin("file");
    fin >> p >> k;
    char s[k];
    for (int i = 0; i < p; ++i) {
       fin >> s;
    for (int j = 0; j < k; ++j) {
            mas[i][j] = 43-s[j];
        }
    }

    fin.close();
    for (int i = 0; i < p; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < k; ++j) {
            if (mas[i][j] >= 1) {
                if (((i-1) >= 0 && mas[i-1][j] >= 0)|| \
                ((i+1) < p_heig && mas[i+1][j] >= 0)|| \
                ((j-1) >= 0 && mas[i][j-1] >= 0) || \
                ((j+1) < k && mas[i][j+1] >= 0)) {
                    if ((i_heig+j_wid) %2 == 0) {
                        mas[i][j] = black;
                        black++;
                    } else {
                        mas[i][j] = white;
                        white++;
                    }
                } else {
                    mas[i][j] = -1;
                    single++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Two things: First you should know that [variable length arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) (like your array `s`) is not in standard C++ yet. Secondly, I hope the value in `k` includes the terminating character for the string you input into `s`.

Comment: Another couple of things: Instead of having the magic number `43` in your code, why not use `'+'` if that's what you mean. And another thing about the string you read into `s`, the string can't contain whitespace as the input operator `>>` stops reading on whitespace.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I use 43 to separate '*' and '.' by ASCII code. What do you mean by saying "use `+`"?
I don't need to read spaces, it's guaranteed that sting will have k first characters '*' and '.'

Comment: Characters are actually just small integer values. In the ASCII character-set the value of the character literal `'+'` is 43. Using magic numbers is, in my opinion, a [code smell](http://blog.codinghorror.com/code-smells/). Using the character literal `'+'` is not much better (technically it's still using a magic number) but at least it's clearer, especially when comparing the code to the input file.

Comment: As for the string `s`, remember that all strings in C++ needs to be terminated, so if the string you read is exactly `k` characters long, you need the array to be `k+1` characters for the terminator character that is automatically added, otherwise you have [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) as your input will write out of bounds of the array.

Comment: An example would be *massively* helpful: What does the input look like, and what kind of bipartite graph do you want to create from that?